# Manage Users page

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I have a practice website and one of the pages is about managing users. I have all the data validation on JS and PHP done. But, for the manage users, I have basically 3 actions: Add, Update, Delete. When I add a user, I check for the password the user will have with a repeat password field. Now, when I will save to the MySQL db, as just not to have the password in plain text (for practice), I use SHA1. Because of this, when I search for a user and will fill up the form, I only have the SHA1 string of the password. What work around can I use to update a users password? I think, not sure, that it would be best just to reset it since that is the purpose of encryption i believe (not to de-encrypt) but then I would have to write the passwords every time I update over and over again unless i just do not update it and just let the user reset it him/her self.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update table set password = sha1(newpass) where password = sha1(oldpass) ???

Comment: But the thing is, let's say I don't want to update the password. Just the username for example. What returns from the ajax call I do on the search is the SHA1 password. So, if I were to fill up the form, it would be with the SHA1 password. When I would update, on my driver page, I SHA1(user_name) on my PHP array I send to the models for inserting, updating, deleting. So it would just SHA1 the SHA1 password already there? Thinking maybe I should just check if those 2 are empty, to not update the password on the db and if they are filled up, then update with SHA1 again.

Comment: If you are returning your sha1 password via ajax call, then what is the meaning of using encryption?...be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, when you save the user's password you encrypt it using SHA1 or MD5. When you are saving a form... if Password and Password Confirm are filled out, only then you actually update the user's password. Else, you simply ignore the password field and update rest of the columns.

So something like:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['password']) && (bool)$_POST['password'] && isset($_POST['password_confirm']) && (bool)$_POST['password_confirm']){
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET password='$password', name='$name'... WHERE id='$id'";
} else {
    $sql = "UPDATE users SET name='$name'... WHERE id='$id'";
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make password field on your form not required and on POST skip it if empty, or write new one if it was typed in.